# Add Months or Years to milliseconds in JSONata

Tags: jsonata

I want to add several months or years to a given date in milliseconds in JSONata, so that it can do something like today plus three months. I didn't find any function to do that job in JSONata, so I implemented a function on my own. I calculated one month in milliseconds and multiply it with the amount of months I want to add. The following code shows the function in action.

```
(
$addMonths := function($time, $months) {
    2628000000 * $months + $time
};

{
  "datePlus3Month": $addMonths($millis(), 3)
}
)
```

This seems to work, but I don't know how accurate it is, because every month hasn't the same amount of days. So is there a better solution to achieve a more accurate result?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. My solution seems rather clunky to me, but it works. Most likely there is a much easier way.

```
$addMonths := function($dateString, $addMonths) {(

    $date := $dateString ~> $toMillis();
    
    $newYear := ($date ~> $fromMillis("[Y,4]") ~> $number());
    $newMonth := ($date ~> $fromMillis("[M]") ~> $number()) + $addMonths;
    $newDay := ($date ~> $fromMillis("[D]") ~> $number());

        $newMonth > 12
    ?   $newYear := $newYear + 1;
    
        $newMonth > 12
    ?   $newMonth := $newMonth - 12;
    
    $lastDay := (
            $newMonth in [1,3,5,7,8,10,12]
        ?   31
        :   $newMonth in [4,6,9,11]
        ?   30
        :   (   $newYear%4=0
                and
                ($newYear%100 != 0 or $newYear%400 = 0)
            ?   29
            :   28)
    );
    
    $newDay > $lastDay 
    ?   $newDay := $lastDay;

    (   $newYear
    &   "-"
    &   $newMonth
    &   "-"
    &   $newDay
    ) ~> $toMillis("[Y]-[M]-[D]")
    ~> $fromMillis()
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to transform into milliseconds, add what you need and then transform back.

`$fromMillis($toMillis("2023-02-02") + 6.307e+10);`

This results in: `"2025-01-31T23:26:40.000Z"`